# Handling background importing of files and notifications in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

New to iOS implementations, rewriting android app to iOS.
I am now handling importing file function with signature (as per https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html):

```
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
```

I can import file here and that's not a problem. I have a couple of questions regarding implementation so that I get this right:

- Is this done in a background thread or should I create a background thread/task for it? Is it okay to handle it in the thread this has been called?
- When I import this, it takes some time (parsing big xml files, importing hundreds my data objects). How should I notify user from UX perspective? Should I send notification once it is done since it is basically background task? Should I create ongoing notification with current progress? My code allows that so it's easy to implement. I just want to know what's best to get it right.

Comment: What do you mean by importing file? Either you want to open any local file.

Comment: I updated question to make it more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying my best to answer your question by breaking it in subparts, hope it helps you

**Q** Is this task done in a background thread?

**Ans** No its is in the main thread, you can use `print(Thread.current)` or  `print(Thread.isMainThread)` to check the thread.

**Q** Should I create a background thread/task for it? Is it okay to handle it in the thread this has been called?

**Ans** It depends on what kind of work you wanted to do. If it's any kind of non-UI related work then Yes, you should use background thread for that GCD are perfect.
As in your case, the file takes some time (parsing big XML files, importing hundreds my data objects) this should be done in the background queue.

**Q** How should I notify user from UX perspective?

**Ans** You can use notification if you want to notify multiple screens(UIViewControllers) other than that delegates are fine.